# How to make Syslog-ng server show facility, priority in the logs it receives from the client?

Tags: logging, ubuntu-16.04, freebsd, syslog, syslog-ng

I'm sending syslogs from my client ( Freebsd) which is using syslogd, to the syslog server which is using Syslog-NG ( Ubuntu 16.04 ) . I'm forwarding all the logs I receive on **local0** facility to the syslog server.

Log shown in the client:

```
Aug 29 08:12:40 <local0.info> host-1 pidgin-process[38529]: 192.168.1.87
```

Log shown in the server:

```
Aug 29 08:12:40  host-1 pidgin-process[38529]: 192.168.1.87
```

As you can see from the server logs, the facility and priority is missing in the message.

syslog.conf in the client:

```
local0.*    /var/log/pidgin.log
local0.*    @192.168.1.122:514
```

syslog-ng.conf in the server:

```
# Version and options info...

source s_local { system(); internal(); };

# Step1: Log source:
source s_network {
    udp(ip("0.0.0.0") port(514));
    };
# So on and so forth
```

At the server side logs, how can I make syslog-ng show the facility,priority in the logs like the client logs do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite the logs in [specific format](http://www.campin.net/syslog-ng/faq.html#template), you can find example [here](http://lists.balabit.hu/pipermail/syslog-ng/2001-January/001153.html). You can find how macros are used in this example to set `destination(d_format_test)`. This also shows how the output would look like.